# Issue: angularjs post data inside then handler

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

I've got the issue that my $http.post is not working correctly. Everytime I send the post it seems like it doesn't send the data at all.

This is my post:

```
  $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: "http://localhost:8080/app/api/v0/user/?access_token=" + UtilService.accessToken,
      data: data
      }).success(function(data){
          console.debug(data);
      }).error(function(data){
          alert("error");
          console.debug(data);
  });
```

The data json:

```
var data = {
    "country": $scope.country,
    "firstname": $scope.firstname,
    "lastname": $scope.lastname,
    "username": $scope.username
}
```

I get the data from a form in my html.

What I tried so far is to add a header with

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

or

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

I also tried `JSON.Stringify(data)` or `angular.toJSson(data)` before sending the data.
I even tried the suggestions from [Make AngularJS $http service behave like jQuery.ajax()](http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/)

But nothing seems to work. When I send the post via Postman everything works fine and I get the expected answer. When I send it via `$http.post()` I just get a empty data as a result and I end up in the error callback.

I am sure that the url I build is correct because of the Postman test. I feel like the issue comes from the data object I send. Even when I send a very simple json like:

```
{
"firstname": "asdf",
"lastname": "asdf"
}
```

I still recieve a empty data object.

I searched for hours now and I have no clue where this misbehaviour comes from. I'm very thankful for any advice!

EDIT: It seems like the issue comes from the fact that I'm trying to call the `$http.post` inside a `promise.then(function(result){ /*where I call the $http.post()*/ })`.

If I make the call outside the `then()` I get an appropriate answer. But I need to wait for the data until I can send my post. So what is wrong with the approach of sending a post inside a `then()`?

EDIT: The hash is the value I need to wait for

```
var deferred = $q.defer(); 

createPasswordHash(email, newPassword1,
                function (hash) {
                    deferred.resolve(hash);
                },
                function (current, total) {

                }
            );

            var promise = deferred.promise;

            promise.then(function (result) {
                var data = {
                     "country": $scope.country,
                     "firstname": $scope.firstname,
                     "lastname": $scope.lastname,
                     "username": $scope.username,
                     "hash": result
                }
                $http.post("http://localhost:8080/app/api/v0/user/?access_token=" + UtilService.accessToken, data).success(function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                }).error(function (data) {
                    alert("error");
                    console.debug(data);
                });
            });
```

I had the same problem when i called the `$http.post()` inside the createPasswordHash method.

Comment: There is nothing wrong to send request in then handler. Just make sure that data is correct before angular post is called. You can check it by logging to console (console.log function).

Comment: You can chain promises that should take care of what you want. Can you post your example, so we can assist in a fix for it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the data is correct cause even if I hardcode any dummydata I just get an empty data object inside the error callback. When I display it it's just a empty line in the console.

Comment: I edited the code and add the part with the promise

Comment: I experience the same issue with $.post inside a promise of other $.post